# Union objects by equal properties and concatenating by different ones in the same array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I get this array and want to join objects when the values of code, name, document and value are all equals and concatenate months and hours. I tried to use lodash without success.

Is there a way to do this using lodash? I tried to use groupBy with unionBy without success .. the results are messy arrays. Thank you.

```
    const arrayOfObject = [
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '158.56',
      month: '082011',
      hours: '20'
    },
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '158.56',
      month: '092011',
      hours: '20'
    },
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '158.56',
      month: '102011',
      hours: '10'
    },
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '169.81',
      month: '042012',
      hours: '10'
    },
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '169.81',
      month: '052012',
      hours: '10'
    }
  ];
```

This is the expected result:

```
const expectedArray = [
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '158.56',
      month: '082011, 092011, 102011',
      hours: '20, 20, 10'
    },
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '169.81',
      month: '042012, 052012',
      hours: '10, 10'
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Hi! Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I really do my research and I just didn't post my code cause it could cause more confusion on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the keys using [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy), and then use [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) to merge the items of each group with [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mergeWith):

```js
const combine = _.flow([
  arr => _.groupBy(arr, o => [o.code, o.name, o.document, o.value].join('-')),
  groups => _.map(groups, g => _.mergeWith(...g, (o, s, k) => {
    if(k === 'month' || k === 'hours') return `${o}, ${s}`;
  }))
]);

 const arrayOfObject = [{"code":"6666","name":"Foo Bar","doc":"60170150166","value":"158.56","month":"082011","hours":"20"},{"code":"6666","name":"Foo Bar","doc":"60170150166","value":"158.56","month":"092011","hours":"20"},{"code":"6666","name":"Foo Bar","doc":"60170150166","value":"158.56","month":"102011","hours":"10"},{"code":"6666","name":"Foo Bar","doc":"60170150166","value":"169.81","month":"042012","hours":"10"},{"code":"6666","name":"Foo Bar","doc":"60170150166","value":"169.81","month":"052012","hours":"10"}];
  
const result = combine(arrayOfObject);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There are many lodash functions that I do not even know how to work like this `_.flow` .. I have to study more about this.

Comment: You're welcome :) Flow creates combines the functions, so the next function, gets the result of the previous.

Answer (score 1):

Using native `Array#reduce()` to create the group object and then `Object.values()` to return resultant array.

To me this is easier to read then combining multiple lodash methods

Note I changed `hours` and month` to arrays as this is typically more usefaul than string...adjust if necessary

```js
const grouped = Object.values(
    arrayOfObject.reduce((a,c)=>{
       const key = [c.code, c.name, c.doc, c.value].join('|');
       a[key] = a[key] || Object.assign({}, c, {month:[],hours:[]});
       a[key].month.push(c.month)
       a[key].hours.push(c.hours);
       return a
    },{})
);

console.log(grouped)
```

```html
<script>
  const arrayOfObject = [
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '158.56',
      month: '082011',
      hours: '20'
    },
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '158.56',
      month: '092011',
      hours: '20'
    },
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '158.56',
      month: '102011',
      hours: '10'
    },
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '169.81',
      month: '042012',
      hours: '10'
    },
    {
      code: '6666',
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      doc: '60170150166',
      value: '169.81',
      month: '052012',
      hours: '10'
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [_.unionBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#unionBy)

```
let groupedObject = _.unionBy(arrayOfObject, (element) => {
  return (element.code && element.name && element.doc && element.value)
})
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oqtLpbxr/

And as T.J. Crowder mentioned in the comments, it would be nice if you at least TRY to do it yourself and post the code as well.

Comment: Doesn't produce expected results though

Comment: ah you are right. didnt see that the month were accumulated